# Vaadin Add on Compatibility for Vaadin 8 add ons

Tags: vaadin8, vaadin14, vaadin23

The following add-ons are supported till Vaadin 8. Are they compatible for Vaadin 14 or 23? If not, any alternative option available?

I have searched both Vaadin Directory and component factory, but cannot find anything similar to this.

May be naming is different, and I cannot find correct alternative.

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/switch

and

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/sizereporter

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The replacement for Switch add-on is the ToggleButton

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/togglebutton-for-flow

For getting actual size of the component you no longer need an add-on, but can use the JavaScript call with return value callback.

```
    Button button = new Button("display width");
    button.setWidth("45%");
    button.addClickListener(event -> {
        button.getElement()
                .executeJs("return $0.clientWidth", button.getElement()).then( width -> {
            Notification.show("Button width "+ width.asNumber());
        });
    });

    add(button);
```